# Module in exact sequence isomorphism

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence, principal-ideal-domains

I'm really struggling with this excercise although it does not seem that hard.
We are given a PID $R$ and a prime element $p \in R$. $M$ is an $R$-module and a short exact sequence is given by $0 \rightarrow R/(p) \rightarrow M \rightarrow R/(p) \rightarrow 0$. We need to show that either $M \cong R/(p) \oplus R/(p)$ or $M \cong R/(p^2)$.

Now I thought of using the fact that $M$ can be written as a direct sum of the form $M \cong R^{\rho} \oplus R/(p_1^{a_1})\oplus \dots \oplus R/(p_k^{a_k})$ where $p_i$ are prime and $a_i$ are positive integers. Also $\rho$ is unique. Now  I want to prove that the only $\rho$ that could let $M$ fit in such an exact sequence is zero and next that only $p$ can be such prime element.

The second part "only $p$ itself can come in" seems the most doable but I cannot see how to start...

Comment: The short exact sequence implies $R/(p) \cong M/N$ where $N$ is a copy of $R/(p)$.  As $p$ annihilates $R/(p)$, this means $pM \subseteq N$, Since $N$ is annihilated by $R/(p)$, we conclude that $p^2M=0$.  Then, with the decomposition you wrote, what are the possibilities for $M$?

Comment: Yes, that seems to work just fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The given information is not sufficient to conclude. One needs to know the maps in the short exact sequence.

Case 1 corresponds to 
$$
0 \to R/(p) \oplus 0 \to R/(p) \oplus R/(p) \to 0 \oplus R/p \to 0,$$
and Case 2 corresonds to
$$
0 \to (p)/(p^2) \to R/(p^2) \to R/(p) \to 0
$$
with the isomorphism $(p)/(p^2) \cong R/(p)$.

Comment: Perhaps I am making some assumption I shouldn't be, but is the information not enough?  If $M$ fits into such a short exact sequence, it must be an $R/(p^2)$-module, and $R/(p^2)$ is an Artinian local ring of length $2$.  Further $M$ must have length $2$, and the only indecomposables over $R/(p^2)$ are $R/(p)$ and $R/(p^2)$.  This only leaves the two desired possibilities for $M$ no?

Comment: Hi @metalspringpro, any $R/(p)$-module $M$ is also an $R/(p^2)$-module since $pM = 0$ implies that $p^2M = 0$. I did not see the condition of $M$ begin indecomposible. If so, this condition eliminates Case 1, and your arguement is correct and mine is not.

Comment: No $M$ need not be indecomposable; as I understood it, the OP was asking why $M$ was reduced to being one of the two possibilities $R/(p^2)$ or $R/(p) \oplus R/(p)$, but not claiming to be able to determine which.